# Synchronising LEDs

Tags: arduino-ide

Say I have 3 LEDs. I want LED1 to blink 5 times. At its third blink, LED2 should start blinking as well, also 5 times. While LED2 is at its 3rd blink, LED3 should start blinking. How do I do this in Arduino? 
Here's what I have.

```
int timeStep = 200; // delay time
int myPins[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}; // array with Pins
int myPinsSize = sizeof(myPins) / sizeof(myPins[0]); // Length of my array
int counter = 0;

void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  for (int i = 0; i < myPinsSize; i++) {
    pinMode(myPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  LEDsequence();
  if(counter >= 9) {
    counter = 0;
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
}

void LEDsequence() {
  if(counter < 5) {
    switchOn(0);
  }
  if(counter >= 2 && counter < 7) {
    switchOn(1);
  }
  if(counter >=4 && counter < 9) {
    switchOn(2);
  }
  delay(timeStep);
  switchAllOff();
}

void switchOn(int index) {
  digitalWrite(myPins[index], HIGH);
}

void switchOff(int index) {
 digitalWrite(myPins[index], LOW);
}

void switchAllOff() {
  for (int i = 0; i < myPinsSize; i++) {
    digitalWrite(myPins[i], LOW);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Michel's answer (this is a bit long to put in a comment):

Rather than using a 2 dimensional array or an array of strings (which is also a 2d array) it would be far more efficient to use a bitmask system.

```
const uint8_t TIME_PERIODS = 20;
const uint8_t NR_LEDS = 3;
const uint8_t ledStates[] = [1,0,1,0,3,0,3,0,7,0,6,0,6,0,4,0,4,0,4,0];
```

and then the loop becomes:

```
  for (int period = 0; period < TIME_PERIODS; period++) 
  { 
    for (int led = 0; led < NR_LEDS; led++)
    {
      switch(led, ledStates[period] & 1<<led ); // set the led on or off
    }
    delay(500); // 0.5 s
  }
```

How this works:
`1<<led` will be 0001 in binary for led=0, 0010 for led = 1, 0100 for led = 2.
So if `ledStates[period]` was 3 (0011 in binary) then `ledStates[period] & 1<<led` will be non-zero for leds 0 and 1 and zero for led 2. The way the switch function is written any non zero value turns the LED on, 0 turns it off.

Why do it this way? Mainly size. Memory is always important, this uses 1 byte per state rather than 3. It could even be expanded to up to 8 LEDs without increasing the amount of memory used.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 3 leds, make a 2 dimensional array, first index for the leds (3), second for the period in which you want to have the led on or off.

E.g.

```
const uint8_t NR_LEDS      = 3;
const uint8_t TIME_PERIODS = 20;

uint8_t period[NR_LEDS][TIME_PERIODS] = [
// Time  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17, 18, 19
        {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, // Led 1
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, // Led 2
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 }}; // Led 3
```

This means over 18 time periods, each state shows which led is on and off.
You can use HIGH or LOW, but that makes the lines too wide.

Now you can easily create a loop:

```
void loop()
{
  for (int period = 0; period  < TIME_PERIODS; period ++) // Time
  { 
    for (int led = 0; led < NR_LEDS; led++)
    {
      switch(led, states[led, period ]); // set the led on or off
    }
    delay(1000); // 1 s
  }
}

void switch(uint8_t led, uint8_t state)
{
  digitalWrite(led, state == 0 ? LOW : HIGH);
}
```

So instead of switchOn and switchOff, use the switch and set it on or off by a parameter.

Also, this way it is very easy to change the schema (you can always visually see it in code). If you want longer schemes you can change the array into strings, like:

```
char* period[NR_LEDS] = [
 // Time 0         10       
 // Time 012345678901234567890
        "10101010100000000000", // LED 1
        "00001010101010000000", // LED 2
        "00000000101010101010", // LED 3
```

And check the index within the correct string and check for '0' and '1' instead of 0 and 1.

Since blinking is done for all leds 'in sync' (meaning during blinking leds change at the same time), you can also define a '1' as blink and '0' as off.

Than change:

```
char* period[NR_LEDS] = [
 // Time 0         10       
 // Time 012345678901234567890
        "10101010100000000000", // LED 1
        "00001010101010000000", // LED 2
        "00000000101010101010", // LED 3
```

to

```
char* period[NR_LEDS] = [
 // Time 0         10       
 // Time 012345678901234567890
        "111110000", // LED 1
        "001111100", // LED 2
        "000011111", // LED 3
```

And change the loop in

```
void loop()
{
  for (int period = 0; period < TIME_PERIODS; period ++) // Time
  { 
    for (int led = 0; led < NR_LEDS; led++)
    {
      switch(led, states[led, period]); // set the led on or off
    }
    delay(500); // 0.5 s

    for (int led = 0; led < NR_LEDS; led++)
    {
       switch(led, '0');
    }
    delay(500); // 0.5 s
  }
}
```

(use a constant for 0.5 s delay) and optionally create a function for the two small for loops above)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I do this in Arduino? Here's what I have.

easy:

1) write a routine that blink a pattern on a given pin;

something like this would work

```
void myblinking(uint8_t pin, uint8_t *ptrn, uint8_t steps) {
  uint8_t index;

  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);  //set pin as output
  for (index=0; index<steps; index++) {
    digitalWrite(pin, !digitalRead(pin)); delay(ptrn[index]); //flip pin, waste sometime
  }
}
```

2. then all you need is to call that routine, like this:

   myblink(LED_PIN0, led_ptrn0, 10); //blink led_pin0, per led_ptrn0, for 10 steps
     myblink(LED_PIN1, led_ptrn1, 20); //blink led_pin1, per led_ptrn1, for 20 steps
     ...

Comment: That would only blink 1 LED at a time, it wouldn't allow you to run 2 different patterns on two different leds at the same time.